# Merge two row results into one row MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

I have a table having following structure:

```
| pid | email | email_type |
| 1   | x     | 1          |
| 1   | y     | 2          |
| 1   | z     | 3          |
| 2   | ab    | 1          |
| 3   | cd    | 2          |
```

Now I want my result for the `pid` parameter in format for `email_type[1 & 2]` only:

Case `pid=1`

```
| pid | email_p | email_w |
| 1   | x       | y       |
```

Case `pid=2`

```
| 2   | ab      | NULL    |
```

Case `pid=3`

```
| 3   | NULL    | cd      |
```

Here `email_p` represents `email_type=1` & `email_w` represents `email_type=2`

I am using following query, and its working fine except for a case `pid=2`. Case I & Case III are successfully fetched. Please provide some solution with good explanation(if possible).

```
SELECT `e`.`pid`, `e`.`email` AS `email_p`, `e1`.`email` AS `email_w` FROM `table1` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `table1` AS `e1` ON e.pid=e1.pid AND e1.email_type=2 WHERE (e.pid IN (1) AND e.email_type=1)
```

It fails when `e.pid = 2` and it returns empty result set & please provide solution `e.pid IN (1,2,3)` holds good for required format.#MYSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT pid,
       MAX(CASE WHEN email_type=1 THEN email END ) as email_p ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN email_type=2 THEN email END ) as email_w 
FROM tableName
WHERE email_type IN (1,2)
GROUP BY pid
```

[**SQL Fiddle DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2fc8/2)